# Margin comments (like MS Word) for [R]markdown

Tags: markdown, r-markdown

In LaTeX one can make MS-Word-like comments using `todonotes` package (documentation [here](https://ctan.org/pkg/todonotes)). Here's an example.

[image: An example of notes.]

(It also has additional options, like making a table of such todonotes.)

Is it possible to do a similar thing in `markdown`/`rmarkdown`?

Thanks in advance!